# How do you use a keyof value in parameter to define the type of another parameter based on an interface

Tags: typescript

If you have a simple function where one parameter is the keyof an interface and another parameter is based that key. How do you type the value to enforce typing instead of using any?

```
interface Config {
    name?: string
    ttl?: number
}

const config: Config = {}

function setConfig(
    key: keyof Config,
    // What typing is needed here to avoid any type
    // This should be either string or number depending on the value of key
    val: any
) {
    config[key] = val
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
function setConfig<K extends keyof Config>(key: K, val: Config[K]) {
  config[key] = val
}
```